# Error while iterating over dataframe column's entries: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, iteritems

Using pandas version 2, I get an error when calling `iteritems`.

```py
for event_id, region in column.iteritems():
    pass
```

The following error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/analyst/anaconda3/envs/outrigger_env/lib/python3.10/site- 
     packages/outrigger/io/gtf.py", line 185, in exon_bedfiles
          for event_id, region in column.iteritems())
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) was removed in `2.0.0` by [*GH45321*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45321).

> **Removed** deprecated *Series.iteritems()*... **use `obj.items` instead**.
> (from [v2.0.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html))

You can use [`items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) wherever you used `iteritems`:

```py
for event_id, region in column.items():
    pass
```