# `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` in simple custom Pyfolio example

Tags: python, pandas, pyfolio

I try to get a custom Pyfolio example running in a Jupyter Notebook on OSx. But I either get

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` with the Pandas > 2.0.0 or

`IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` with the Pandas < 2.0.0.

These are my steps for the latest Pandas version:

1. Create a `requirements.txt` with

```
pyfolio
jupyter
pandas
```

2. `virtualenv --python python3 env`
3. `source ./env/bin/activate`
4. `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
5. `jupyter notebook`
   The Notebook looks like this:

```
import pyfolio as pf
import pandas as pd
```

```
return_values = {
    '2023-01-01': 0.005,
    '2023-01-02': -0.002,
    '2023-01-03': 0.003,
    '2023-01-04': -0.002,
    '2023-01-05': 0.006,
}
dates = pd.to_datetime(list(return_values.keys()))

returns = pd.Series(list(return_values.values()), index=dates)
returns
```

```
data = {
    'AAPL': [5000, 5200, 5100, 5300, 5400],
    'MSFT': [3000, 3050, 3100, 3150, 3200],
    'GOOG': [7000, 6900, 7100, 7200, 7300],
}

dates = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

positions = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates)
positions['cash'] = [1000, 1500, 1200, 1100, 1300]
positions
```

```
data = {
    'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
    'symbol': ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AAPL'],
    'amount': [10, -5, 15, 11, -4],  # Positive for buys, negative for sells
    'price': [150, 200, 1000, 240, 110]
}
transactions = pd.DataFrame(data)
transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['date'])
transactions.set_index('date', inplace=True)
transactions
```

`pf.create_full_tear_sheet(returns, positions=positions, transactions=transactions)`

With that last call I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/_n/_pkw_mkx6z72n2b2jy6vj64w0000gn/T/ipykernel_97539/850986836.py in ?()
----> 1 pf.create_full_tear_sheet(returns, positions=positions, transactions=transactions)

~/privat/trading/pyfoliotest/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/tears.py in ?(returns, positions, transactions, market_data, benchmark_rets, slippage, live_start_date, sector_mappings, bayesian, round_trips, estimate_intraday, hide_positions, cone_std, bootstrap, unadjusted_returns, style_factor_panel, sectors, caps, shares_held, volumes, percentile, turnover_denom, set_context, factor_returns, factor_loadings, pos_in_dollars, header_rows, factor_partitions)
    197 
    198     positions = utils.check_intraday(estimate_intraday, returns,
    199                                      positions, transactions)
    200 
--> 201     create_returns_tear_sheet(
    202         returns,
    203         positions=positions,
    204         transactions=transactions,

~/privat/trading/pyfoliotest/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py in ?(*args, **kwargs)
     48     def call_w_context(*args, **kwargs):
     49         set_context = kwargs.pop('set_context', True)
     50         if set_context:
     51             with plotting_context(), axes_style():
---> 52                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     53         else:
     54             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~/privat/trading/pyfoliotest/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/tears.py in ?(returns, positions, transactions, live_start_date, cone_std, benchmark_rets, bootstrap, turnover_denom, header_rows, return_fig)
    492 
    493     if benchmark_rets is not None:
    494         returns = utils.clip_returns_to_benchmark(returns, benchmark_rets)
    495 
--> 496     plotting.show_perf_stats(returns, benchmark_rets,
    497                              positions=positions,
    498                              transactions=transactions,
    499                              turnover_denom=turnover_denom,

~/privat/trading/pyfoliotest/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py in ?(returns, factor_returns, positions, transactions, turnover_denom, live_start_date, bootstrap, header_rows)
    644                                             APPROX_BDAYS_PER_MONTH)
    645         perf_stats = pd.DataFrame(perf_stats_all, columns=['Backtest'])
    646 
    647     for column in perf_stats.columns:
--> 648         for stat, value in perf_stats[column].iteritems():
    649             if stat in STAT_FUNCS_PCT:
    650                 perf_stats.loc[stat, column] = str(np.round(value * 100,
    651                                                             1)) + '%'

~/privat/trading/pyfoliotest/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, name)
   6200             and name not in self._accessors
   6201             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   6202         ):
   6203             return self[name]
-> 6204         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

As far as I can see in the [DocStrings](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/blob/master/pyfolio/tears.py#L89), it's not like the positions should be a dataframe and the `iteritems` refers to a dataframe but really a Series.
As can be seen in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76202088/1743551), `iteritems` got deprecated in Pandas>2.0.0. So I've tried to downgrade it. Now I actually see the backtest result table (without graphs) but I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 pf.create_full_tear_sheet(returns, positions=positions, transactions=transactions)

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/tears.py:201, in create_full_tear_sheet(returns, positions, transactions, market_data, benchmark_rets, slippage, live_start_date, sector_mappings, bayesian, round_trips, estimate_intraday, hide_positions, cone_std, bootstrap, unadjusted_returns, style_factor_panel, sectors, caps, shares_held, volumes, percentile, turnover_denom, set_context, factor_returns, factor_loadings, pos_in_dollars, header_rows, factor_partitions)
    195     returns = txn.adjust_returns_for_slippage(returns, positions,
    196                                               transactions, slippage)
    198 positions = utils.check_intraday(estimate_intraday, returns,
    199                                  positions, transactions)
--> 201 create_returns_tear_sheet(
    202     returns,
    203     positions=positions,
    204     transactions=transactions,
    205     live_start_date=live_start_date,
    206     cone_std=cone_std,
    207     benchmark_rets=benchmark_rets,
    208     bootstrap=bootstrap,
    209     turnover_denom=turnover_denom,
    210     header_rows=header_rows,
    211     set_context=set_context)
    213 create_interesting_times_tear_sheet(returns,
    214                                     benchmark_rets=benchmark_rets,
    215                                     set_context=set_context)
    217 if positions is not None:

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py:52, in customize.<locals>.call_w_context(*args, **kwargs)
     50 if set_context:
     51     with plotting_context(), axes_style():
---> 52         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     53 else:
     54     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/tears.py:504, in create_returns_tear_sheet(returns, positions, transactions, live_start_date, cone_std, benchmark_rets, bootstrap, turnover_denom, header_rows, return_fig)
    494     returns = utils.clip_returns_to_benchmark(returns, benchmark_rets)
    496 plotting.show_perf_stats(returns, benchmark_rets,
    497                          positions=positions,
    498                          transactions=transactions,
   (...)
    501                          live_start_date=live_start_date,
    502                          header_rows=header_rows)
--> 504 plotting.show_worst_drawdown_periods(returns)
    506 vertical_sections = 11
    508 if live_start_date is not None:

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py:1664, in show_worst_drawdown_periods(returns, top)
   1648 def show_worst_drawdown_periods(returns, top=5):
   1649     """
   1650     Prints information about the worst drawdown periods.
   1651 
   (...)
   1661         Amount of top drawdowns periods to plot (default 5).
   1662     """
-> 1664     drawdown_df = timeseries.gen_drawdown_table(returns, top=top)
   1665     utils.print_table(
   1666         drawdown_df.sort_values('Net drawdown in %', ascending=False),
   1667         name='Worst drawdown periods',
   1668         float_format='{0:.2f}'.format,
   1669     )

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py:991, in gen_drawdown_table(returns, top)
    973 """
    974 Places top drawdowns in a table.
    975 
   (...)
    987     Information about top drawdowns.
    988 """
    990 df_cum = ep.cum_returns(returns, 1.0)
--> 991 drawdown_periods = get_top_drawdowns(returns, top=top)
    992 df_drawdowns = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(top)),
    993                             columns=['Net drawdown in %',
    994                                      'Peak date',
    995                                      'Valley date',
    996                                      'Recovery date',
    997                                      'Duration'])
    999 for i, (peak, valley, recovery) in enumerate(drawdown_periods):

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py:956, in get_top_drawdowns(returns, top)
    954 drawdowns = []
    955 for t in range(top):
--> 956     peak, valley, recovery = get_max_drawdown_underwater(underwater)
    957     # Slice out draw-down period
    958     if not pd.isnull(recovery):

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py:895, in get_max_drawdown_underwater(underwater)
    893 valley = np.argmin(underwater)  # end of the period
    894 # Find first 0
--> 895 peak = underwater[:valley][underwater[:valley] == 0].index[-1]
    896 # Find last 0
    897 try:

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5320, in Index.__getitem__(self, key)
   5317 if is_integer(key) or is_float(key):
   5318     # GH#44051 exclude bool, which would return a 2d ndarray
   5319     key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key, warn_float=True)
-> 5320     return getitem(key)
   5322 if isinstance(key, slice):
   5323     # This case is separated from the conditional above to avoid
   5324     # pessimization com.is_bool_indexer and ndim checks.
   5325     result = getitem(key)

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py:358, in DatetimeLikeArrayMixin.__getitem__(self, key)
    350 """
    351 This getitem defers to the underlying array, which by-definition can
    352 only handle list-likes, slices, and integer scalars
    353 """
    354 # Use cast as we know we will get back a DatetimeLikeArray or DTScalar,
    355 # but skip evaluating the Union at runtime for performance
    356 # (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44624)
    357 result = cast(
--> 358     "Union[DatetimeLikeArrayT, DTScalarOrNaT]", super().__getitem__(key)
    359 )
    360 if lib.is_scalar(result):
    361     return result

File ~/privat/trading/options-backtesting/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py:289, in NDArrayBackedExtensionArray.__getitem__(self, key)
    283 def __getitem__(
    284     self: NDArrayBackedExtensionArrayT,
    285     key: PositionalIndexer2D,
    286 ) -> NDArrayBackedExtensionArrayT | Any:
    287     if lib.is_integer(key):
    288         # fast-path
--> 289         result = self._ndarray[key]
    290         if self.ndim == 1:
    291             return self._box_func(result)

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

```
print(pf.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)
```

returns:

```
0.9.2
2.1.4
```

What can I do to get this simple Pyfolio example running from a recent version in a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Pyfolio is probably simply not updated to Pandas > 2.0.0 yet :-(. See https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/704

Answer (score 0):

That's [the corresponding bug ticket](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/704) in Pyfolio. It is simply not updated to Pandas > 2.0.0 because it's not maintained anymore.

I've got it working by using pyfolio-reloaded. See:
https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/690